# asp.net webforms c# - user input during Server side function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know the approach to this has to be a little different.

During the execution of a code behind event, e.g when button clicked "complete task".
I need to take various actions depending on a user input during the server side flow. Here is a simple example..

So during the c# function I take the current record ID and gather some related database information, I need to either take action A or Action B depending on an input from the user.

So am I on the correct track to say I will actually need 3 functions.

1. Button click (complete)

   I will have to come to the end of this function when I need to run a client side confirmation, there is no way around this.. then depending on the button run either the 2 below. In a desktop application the 1 function would do but am I correct with this?
2. Function (action a)
3. Function (action b).

Comment: Yes that would be correct, having a separate method for doing specific task

Comment: This is a *web site*. You can't ask for user confirmation. There is no user. Change the application to determine whether confirmation is needed *before* you start processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this.
I would create a modal popup, which I show on Button_onClick function to let the user choose between other two buttons (normally hidden).
If you know AjaxControlToolkit, you could do this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbAnchor" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Choice_Popup" runat="server"
    CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" Enabled="True"
    PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="lbAnchor" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<div class="col-md-3" id="Panel1">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            CHOOSE YOUR FUNCTION
            <span id="ButtonCancel" class="pull-right close" data-effect="fadeOut">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonFunction1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="FUNCTION 1" Style="margin-top: 5px;" OnClick="ButtonFunction1_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonFunction2" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="FUNCTION 2" Style="margin-top: 5px;" OnClick="ButtonFunction2_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And at the end of Button_onClick

```
Choice_Popup.Show();
```

Just use this code for hint, as I could not try it live